# How to implement google authentication in an Angular project?

Tags: angular, google-authentication

I have to implement Google Authentication in an Angular project but I can't find an article that explains it properly.

I tried reading the documentation but it didn't really work for me.

Can someone recomend an article or provide a good explanation?

I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

i used this article to start,
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

** most of the logic should be in the back-end side,

for example if you want to make some kind of authorization for a specific endpoint, the frontend should only send the code in the request and your back end should validate the key using a special private key he holds.

hope it helps